# How would I code when a item has been selected in a JList?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jlist

I have a JList with 5 options in it and when one of the items becomes selected or clicked i want the text area next to it to show a paragraph of text relative to the item clicked. It should do this for each item in the list but I cant seem to find how to do it in the API

How would my program know if an item in the JList was selected so I can work with the data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`addListSelectionListener`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener%29).  You can create a subclass (anonymous or not) of [`ListSelectionListener`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) that does the work you want.

```
myList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
{
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent ev)
  {
    // handle ev
  } 
});
```

Comment: Would using getSource() retrieve the value in a string of the selected item? That is what I want. To retrieve the item in a string of the actual selected item.

Comment: @Kitsune, the source is the JList.  You can easily get the selected items with `((JList)ev.getSource()).getSelectedValues()`

Comment: Thanks alot! youve helped me so much! Youve been added as the answer and got an up! :P

Answer (score 1):

You should register a Listener for events on your JList.  When the Swing UI fires one off, this Listener class will get the message and react accordingly.