# Select a item from a JLIST and update a form with all db info from that selected id

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdbc, jlist

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114721/how-would-i-code-when-a-item-has-been-selected-in-a-jlist), but didn't work for me =(

I have a DB named clients with id,name,phone and email. When I register a client, his name and id is shown on a Jlist. Now I want to click on the name, inside the Jlist and "search" all data for this client (id, name, phone and email).
I already have the textField´s to link the data, but isn't working...

What I did:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
client_listClientes.setModel(model);

try {

   String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ANAIA_DB";
   String uName = "*****";    
   String uPass = "*****";

   con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
   stmt = con.createStatement();

   String sql = "SELECT * FROM APP.CLIENTS";

   int id_col = rs.getInt("clientID"); // I need to make this work.. when i select a value, it gives me the id for that client

   ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM APP.CLIENTS WHERE CLIENTID='"+id_col+"'");
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

   while (RS.next()){

      String name = rs.getString("clientName");
      client_textName.setText(name);
      String phone = rs.getString("clientPhone");
      client_textPhone.setText(phone);
      String email = rs.getString("clientMail");
      client_textMail.setText(email);


   }
}
catch (SQLException err) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.this, err.getMessage());
}
```

I read that i have to use a listener, but i tried the exemple from the other question and didnt work =/

Answer (score 1):

Just load all the data into a `Client` object at one time, instead of trying to go back and hit the db each time.

```
class Client {
    int id;
    String name;
    String phone;
    String email;

    // getter and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " : " + name;
    }
}
```

Then you can can just load all the data into the client objects and just add them to the model

```
 ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM APP.CLIENTS");
 ...
 while (RS.next()){

     Client client = new Client();
     client.setId(rs.getInt("id");
     client.setName(rs.getString("clientName"));
     client.setPhone(rs.getString("clientPhone"));
     client.setEmail(rs.getString("clientMail");

     model.addElement(client);
 }
```

Then wehn you click on the JList, just extract the `Client` object selected and use the `getters` to set the text fields

```
 client_listClientes.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
         if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
              JList list = (JList)e.getSource();
              Client client = (Client)list.getSelectedValue();
              textfield.setText(client.getEmail());
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Hummm just got home and tried it.. Since im already using "ResultSet RS" its giving me an error "ResultSet not open. Operation next not permited. Verify that autocomit is OFF"

Comment: In your current select you are only selecting one row. I am simply telling you to select all rows and add them to the client object. If you need to reformat your code, then do it. I'm not telling you to use two result sets.